# Syslog-ng failing, unable to resolve 0.0.0.0

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, syslog-ng

I am rebuilding my Raspberry Pi from scratch and following my docs that I keep with regards to what I install and configure, so that I can quickly get the system rebuilt.  In this instance I am using Rasbian Lite - Buster.

One of the packages I use is system-ng.  I have a config file that I am using from my previous build, that worked fine.  I merely just had to add a @version header to the file as this is now a requirement.

In that file, I open up the box to accept syslog messages from the network so I can configure other machines to log to it...

```
source s_net { udp(ip(0.0.0.0) port(514)); };
```

With this in the config, when the pi boots, the syslog-ng service fails to start.  Enabling debug logging by editing the service, shows me the error message of "Error resolving hostname; host='0.0.0.0'."  This stops the service from running, but after boot, if I logon and manually start the service, it starts fine.

What is wrong here?  Is this because the network isn't ready when it is trying to start?

Config as per request:

```
@version: 3.19

# Options
# =======

# Turn off the annoying MARK messages
options { mark_freq(0); };


# Sources
# =======

# Open up the PI to accept syslog messages from any network connection on port 514 (syslog)
source s_net { udp(ip(127.0.0.1) port(514)); };

# OpenVPN log file
source s_openvpn_log { file("var/log/openvpn.log" follow-freq(1)); };


# Destinations
# ============

# Log messages from the sky router
destination d_router { file("/var/log/router.log"); };

# Email alerts
destination d_emailalerts { program("/etc/syslog-alert.sh" template("$MSG\n") ); };
destination d_vpn_incoming_emailalerts { program("/etc/syslog-alert.sh" template("Incoming OpenVPN connection from ${sky.c13}\n") ); };


# Filters
# =======

# Filter for the Sky Router
filter f_router { host( "192.168.0.1" ); };

# Filters for email alerts
filter f_openvpn_connection { message( "OpenVPNIN=ptm0.1 OUT= " ); };
filter f_openvpn_connected { message( "Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]" ); };
filter f_sshd { program( "sshd" ); };
filter f_login_events { message( "Accepted password|Accepted publickey|login successful|failed to log in|Failed password" ); };

# Filters for warning messages (red dmesg)
filter f_red_dmesg { level(warn) and not facility(auth,authpriv,cron,daemon,mail,news); };


# Parsers
# =======

# Parser for the Sky Router log messages
parser p_router_msg { csv-parser( columns("sky.c1","sky.c2","sky.c3","sky.c4","sky.c5","sky.c6","sky.c7","sky.c8","sky.c9","sky.c10","sky.c11","sky.c12","sky.c13") delimiters(" ") ); };


# Rules
# =====

# Log messages from the network for the sky router to the router log file destination
log { source(s_net); filter(f_router); destination(d_router); };

# Send an alert for OpenVPN messages in the sky router syslog messages
log { source(s_net); filter(f_router); filter(f_openvpn_connection); parser(p_router_msg); destination(d_vpn_incoming_emailalerts); };

# Send an alert for someone logging into the sky router
log { source(s_net); filter(f_router); filter(f_login_events); destination(d_emailalerts); };

# Send an alert for a user logging in to SSH terminal
log { source(s_src); filter(f_sshd); filter(f_login_events); destination(d_emailalerts); };

# Send connection events from the openvpn log file
log { source(s_openvpn_log); filter(f_openvpn_connected); destination(d_emailalerts); };

# Send email alerts for any errors
log { source(s_src); filter(f_red_dmesg); destination(d_emailalerts); };
```

NetStat as requested:

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:34771         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6736/Plex Plug-in [
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      461/dnsmasq
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:62966           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      430/python
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      504/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:33400           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      714/Plex Plug-in [c
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:32600         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      677/Plex Tuner Serv
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16597/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8123            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18650/python3.6
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      515/smbd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:58846         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      430/python
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:33443           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      714/Plex Plug-in [c
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:45635         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      618/Plex Plug-in [c
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      515/smbd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16597/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8112            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      585/python
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:45713         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      714/Plex Plug-in [c
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:32401         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      453/Plex Media Serv
tcp        0      1 192.168.0.10:48838      192.168.0.56:80         SYN_SENT    -
tcp        0      1 192.168.0.10:49956      192.168.0.54:80         SYN_SENT    -
tcp        1      0 127.0.0.1:44682         127.0.0.1:45635         CLOSE_WAIT  677/Plex Tuner Serv
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.10:43146      82.4.2.106:32400        ESTABLISHED 453/Plex Media Serv
tcp        0      1 192.168.0.10:44806      192.168.0.50:80         SYN_SENT    -
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.10:445        192.168.0.102:40834     ESTABLISHED 6746/smbd
tcp      309      0 192.168.0.10:41560      192.168.0.100:8001      ESTABLISHED 18650/python3.6
tcp        0      1 192.168.0.10:52512      192.168.0.47:80         SYN_SENT    -
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.10:37582      99.80.242.242:443       CLOSE_WAIT  677/Plex Tuner Serv
tcp        0      1 192.168.0.10:46036      192.168.0.49:80         SYN_SENT    -
tcp        0      1 192.168.0.10:55410      192.168.0.43:80         SYN_SENT    -
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.10:38616      192.168.0.186:32400     ESTABLISHED 453/Plex Media Serv
tcp        0      1 192.168.0.10:42542      192.168.0.46:80         SYN_SENT    -
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.10:50288      139.162.219.82:443      ESTABLISHED 453/Plex Media Serv
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.10:50080      192.168.0.154:8009      ESTABLISHED 18650/python3.6
tcp        0   1536 192.168.0.10:22         192.168.0.186:5534      ESTABLISHED 9125/sshd: pi [priv
tcp        1      0 127.0.0.1:44684         127.0.0.1:45635         CLOSE_WAIT  677/Plex Tuner Serv
tcp        0      1 192.168.0.10:33642      192.168.0.48:80         SYN_SENT    -
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.10:51014      99.81.213.165:80        TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      1 192.168.0.10:40066      192.168.0.51:80         SYN_SENT    -
tcp        0      1 192.168.0.10:44180      192.168.0.40:80         SYN_SENT    -
tcp        0      1 192.168.0.10:58806      192.168.0.55:80         SYN_SENT    -
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.10:445        192.168.0.186:3025      ESTABLISHED 30277/smbd
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      461/dnsmasq
tcp6       0      0 :::62966                :::*                    LISTEN      430/python
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      504/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      515/smbd
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      515/smbd
tcp6       0      0 :::32400                :::*                    LISTEN      453/Plex Media Serv
```

Comment: That syntax seems perfectly correct, and shouldn't require any sort of hostname resolution. Can you post the entire configuration?

Comment: Isn't an other service already bound to port 514? What does netstat -antp say?

Comment: Ive checked for other ports, and that seems to be clear.  Also, if I add 'After=network-online.target' to the service definition file, it seems to resolve the issue.

Config has been added to original question

Comment: @RobertFekete, netstat added.  Note, this is with the "After" edit to the service definition file.

Comment: It might be nothing, but can you try adding quotes to the IP parameter, like ip("0.0.0.0")

Comment: Or try using the default-network-drivers() source: https://support.oneidentity.com/technical-documents/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/administration-guide/source-read-receive-and-collect-log-messages/default-network-drivers-receive-and-parse-common-syslog-messages